# Golang for Windows tesseract-ocr 4.0 dev compilation error

Tags: leptonica

I would like to use golang package for tesseract-ocr, so i have followed exactly the [installation instructions](https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract). I have installed tesseract-ocr 4.0 dev for Windows, but unfortunately i get the following error when i try to run the git example

```
# github.com/otiai10/gosseract
tessbridge.cpp:5:34: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory
 #include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

For your better assistance, i attach you the following information regarding my golang environment:

[image]

Any hint regarding successful leptonica-dev installation in Windows would help me a lot!